# use grepl() to match multiple patterns on data R

Tags: r

This command works to subset the data `filelist` to remove all "jpg" files.

```
filetype.isnotjpg <- setdiff(filelist, subset(filelist, grepl("\\.jpg$", filelist)))
```

So this takes the string "filelist" which contains names of files from a directory. I want to return all files that are not of type "jpg", "doc", "pdf", "xls", etc. I want to be able to specify as many types as I want to filter the list.

Ideally something like

```
target.files <- setdiff(filelist, subset(filelist, grepl( 
    c("\\.jpg$", "\\.doc$", "\\.pdf$", "\\xls$"), filelist)
```

This recursive algorithm works to do what I want:

```
a <- setdiff(files.list, subset(files.list, grepl("\\.tmp", files.list, ignore.case = TRUE)))

a <- setdiff(a, subset(a, grepl("\\.jpg", a, ignore.case = TRUE)))
a <- setdiff(a, subset(a, grepl("\\.pdf", a, ignore.case = TRUE)))
a <- setdiff(a, subset(a, grepl("\\.tif", a, ignore.case = TRUE)))
```

etc. Something like apply() might work? I'm new to R sorry.

The solution of 42 works:

```
      target.files <- setdiff(
        files.list, 
        subset(files.list, 
               grepl( 
                 paste(
                   c("\\.jpg", "\\.doc", "\\.pdf", 
                     "\\.xls", "\\.tif", "\\.docx", "\\.xlsx", "\\.jpeg"), 
                   collapse="|") , 
                 files.list, 
                 ignore.case = TRUE)))
```

Comment: How about a reproducible example

Comment: You had some misspellings of `grepl` which I fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `file_ext` in `tools` to extract the extension from a filename. Then you can just see if they are in your list and use standard vector subsetting:

```
filelist[!(tools::file_ext(filelist) %in% c("jpg","jpeg","doc","pdf","xls"))]
```

If you need to ignore case, you can wrap a `tolower` around the list or extensions.

Answer (score 3):

I would try `paste()`-ing with a collapsing separator of "|" which is the OR operator for regex:

```
target.files <- setdiff(filelist, subset(filelist, grepl( paste(
c("\\.jpg$", "\\.doc$", "\\.pdf$", "\\xls$"), collapse="|") , filelist)
```

Did you know that the `list.files` function also accepts a pattern argument so you could do this in a single step with something like:

```
 my_files <- list.files(path="/path/to/dir/", 
                        pattern=paste( c("\\.jpg$", "\\.doc$", "\\.pdf$", "\\xls$"), 
                                       collapse="|") )
```

Comment: this works, i can generate the string for now. The file.list comes from an sql database, so list.files() wouldn't be an option.